# I can't create ssh chain tunnel

Tags: firefox, ssh, internet, tor, tunnel

I have two remote Ubuntu servers - vps1 and vps2. I want to create ssh tunnel for Firefox, that runs on my PC, to connect first to vps1 and then from vps1 to vps2. This doesn't have to be implemented with one command.

I can create the ssh tunnel to the first vps with the command: `ssh -D 9999 -i keyfile1 ubuntu1@ip_address` and Firefox can connect through the tunnel and browse internet. If i check the IP address it shows the IP of the first vps server - vps1.

But how to create the ssh tunnel from vps1 to vps2 and forward Firefox through it. If i try the same command to create the tunnel from vps1 to vps2 it creates the tunnel but Firefox doesn't connect through it. If i check the IP address it still shows the ip address of the first vps.

My goal is to launch firefox from my local machine, have it connect to vps2 through vps1 and browse the internet in such a way that if I visit a website with Firefox and someone checks my IP, they will see the IP of the second vps as a source.

Comment: Where is firefox running? On your local machine? On vpn2? Vpn1? Please [edit] your post and clarify.

Comment: Firefox is running on my PC.